# get the number of videos on a youtube playlist with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube, playlist

i want to know the videos number on a playlist (youtube)
this is an example of a json playlist

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/80D426344F3DE8B6?v=2&alt=json

the code :

```
var playlistURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+config.playlist+'?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var youURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';

//retrieve json
jQuery.getJSON(playlistURL, function(data) {

    jQuery.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.jQueryt;
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = youURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
            var videosCount = ??????

    });
});
```

thanks advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is : data.feed.entry.length

Answer (score 0):

The total amount of videos in a playlist are stored in a span class called `item-count`.

```
var $data = $('<div>').html(data);
var videosCount = $data.find('.item-count');
```